# Changing subelements class with JQuery

Tags: jquery, css, html, addclass, removeclass

I am trying to change the class of all div element with the id "led1" which resides in another div with the id 1.

```
<div class="MACHINE">
  <div id="1" class="HOST">EMPTY
    <div id="led1" class="LED"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I use the following code but it only change the text "EMPTY" and not the class. Below is a piece of my js file is use to change the class. For some reason it doesn't work...

I hope that someone can direct my into the right direction.

```
$.each(data, function(hst) {
    $.each(data[hst], function(key, value){
        var currClass =  $('#led'+ key).attr('class');
        switch(value)
        {
           case 'EMPTY': $('#led' + key).removeClass(currClass).addClass('LED ' + value);$('#' + key).html(value);break;
           case 'PROCESSING': $('#led' + key).removeClass(currClass).addClass('LED ' + value);$('#' + key).html(value);break;
           case 'FINISHED': $('#led' + key).removeClass(currClass).addClass('LED ' + value);$('#' + key).html(value);break;
           case 'REPLACE': $('#led' + key).removeClass(currClass).addClass('LED ' + value);$('#' + key).html(value);break;
         }
      });
   });
   },
   error: function() {
     alert('Ello');
     console.log("ERROR: show_host_status")     
   },
 });
},   
}
```

Comment: Do you have elements with the same ID?

Comment: IDs a) shouldn't start with a number and b) should be unique. "I am trying to change the class of all div element with the id "led1"" implies you have more than one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a problem.

```
 case 'EMPTY': $('#led' + key).removeClass(currClass).addClass('LED ' + value);$('#' + key).html(value);break;
```

It sets the "HOST"'s HTML to whatever value is (thus removing the LED).  Try something like this.

```
<div class="MACHINE">
    <div id="1" class="HOST">
        <div class='host-value'>EMPTY</div>
        <div id="led1" class="LED"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and your code in the case statements as

```
 case 'EMPTY': $('#led' + key).removeClass(currClass).addClass('LED ' + value);$(".host-value", $('#' + key)).html(value);break;
```

Then you have to change how your getting the "value" since its not just straight element its from #key .host-value

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in other responses, the answer is technically:

`ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".")`.

apologies to: @dgvid

Try changing `<div id="1">` to `<div id="host-1">` and update your script accordingly